# What is the right expression to say "I expose myself to life". Would it be 露呈{ろてい}, 露見{ろけん} or something else?

Tags: word-choice, verbs

I tried to write the expression "to expose yourself to life". I would like to express "to expose" like as in "I expose myself to live, with all things, bad and good, that could happen".

In this case, I don't know if I have to use 露呈{ろてい} or 露見{ろけん}.

Comment: Hello @Nuria Garcia welcome to Japanese StackExchange! If you have more context or background it might be helpful to answer your question. Also, what are the attemps you've come up with so far trying to express what you want?

Answer (score 3):

Just a short answer, 露見 or 露呈 is used usually in the sense that something negative (e.g. bribery) is found out or betrayed. So the answer is that both does not work for *to expose sb. to sth.*

In terms of dictionary translation, the *[expose](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/expose/#ej-29717)* means 晒す（さらす）, but 「（人を）人生にさらす」 is not an idiomatic combination. You would need to choose different words depending on the context. E.g. if you mean by *expose myself to life, good or bad* "accept", it would be 受け入れる or "confront" then 立ち向かう etc.